# How can i identify the relation=NoFOLLOW links

Tags: php, html, regex

I would like to know how can we identify the Nofollow relation in the URL through PHP REGEX.

```
<a href="abc.html" rel="NOFOLLOW">How to check NOFOLLOW<a>
```

Please give me the solution to findout this things

Comment: Is it expected the HTML will be malformed like in your example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try with something such as...

```
preg_match('/<a.+?rel="nofollow".*?>[\s\S]*?<\/a>/i', $html);
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/I8dgby).

But **you are better off using a HTML parser** which deals with things that a regex can not.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;

$dom->loadHTML($html);

$anchors = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');

foreach($anchors as $anchor) {
   if ($anchor->hasAttribute('rel')) {
      $rel = preg_split('/\s+/', strtolower($anchor->getAttribute('rel')));

      if (in_array('nofollow', $rel)) {
         echo 'This anchor is "nofollow"\'d.';
      }
   }
}
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/uk27XO).